# Silverlight 5 Install Project using InstallShield - which one do I use?

Tags: silverlight, installshield

Well I think this might be the final question for this Silverlight 5 project.

I just installed the InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio 2012 and no I am faced with a dilemma. Which installation project to use?

The project is a Silverlight WCF application and I hope that is a simple enough description to go on. What is required is that the client side sees the web environment and the server side has the WCF services (of course).

I have not worked with this kind of project before so there may be some configuring certain pieces to go certain places and I am very unfamiliar with how all this works. The Installer projects available are as follows:

Setup Project,
Merge Module Project,
Setup Library Project,
Bootstrapper Project,
C# Custom Action Project,
VB Custom Action Project,
C++ Custom Action Project

Which one would I use to create an Installer for this Silverlight 5 WCF solution?

Comment: For silverlight we don't need an installer. A Web server and publishing are ok.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too ... but my boss was asking about an Installer kind of project. So, I asked ... :-D

Comment: Boss'es :) always ask for something.

Comment: Well .. to clarify ... we won't have remote access to some of our clients' servers so we need an installer to configure the files to go all into the right place. 

So far we are just using the Generic InstallShield project to configure an installer to do all that work ...